# Can you help me with a short code that can print itself?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define q(k)main(){return!puts(#k"\nq("#k")");}
q(#define q(k)main(){return!puts(#k"\nq("#k")");})
```

This code can print itself on the screen,however,I have a difficulty in reading it,especially that two #K,how does it work?I know how #define q(k)  2*k works,but I really have no idea about this code.Please help me to analyse it!thank you!

Comment: Hooray! The [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) is back!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplify the call and use your compiler's preprocessor to see what is going on:

```
#define q(k)main(){puts(#k"hello("#k")");}
q(argument)
```

Running `gcc -E` on that gives you:

```
main(){puts("argument""hello(""argument"")");}
```

As you can see, what happens is that the argument to the `q` macro gets transformed into a string (because is is used as `#k` - this is sometimes called "stringification"). There is no other magic going on here.

Comment: Thank you,I learn a new skill----gcc -E:),I tried as you modified before,but i don't know gcc -E,i guess it should bemain(){puts(argument"hello("argument")");},but it doesn't work.you are kind and smart.

Comment: All the quotes are added. `#k` makes a string out of the argument, `k` would put the token as is.